# Evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(e^{2x}+1)(x^2+1)^2} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am stuck evaluating the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(e^{2x}+1)(x^2+1)^2} dx,$$
but I do know that the answer should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I have tried using residue calculus, but I did not get very far. Can anyone help me approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use the residue theorem seems the only reasonable option. If this is what you tried you should post your attemp, otherwise you woldn't get many answers.

Comment: Hint $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(e^{2x}+1)(x^2+1)^2} dx= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} dx=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: @Quanto I'm interested- how did you determine that equality between those integrals?

Comment: @KStarGamer - In general
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x^2)}{e^{2x}+1} dx
= \int_{0}^{\infty} {f(x^2)}dx $$

Comment: @KStarGamer - Not complicated; just break LHS into two

Comment: Oh yeah of course. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Quanto's comment, once you see that identity, your integral is simply $\int_0^\infty dx/(x+1/x)^2=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x-1/x)^2+4}=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+4}=\pi/4$ by Glasser's Master theorem.